# Node Quasar App + Express API as a Single Action Executable

Tags: node.js, deployment, quasar-framework, quasar

I have started a quasar 2.0+ project in one repo, and in another repo, I have the API the application will use. It uses express. So far so good, things are going wonderful. However, in the future, I very much want to "package" this up as an EXE file.  and I am looking for some help. For starters the relevant part of my package.json looks like this:

```
"pkg": {
  "assets": [
    "public/**/*",
    ".env"
  ],
  "sourceType": "module",
  "targets": [
    "node18-win-x64"
  ],
    "outputPath": "dist"
}
```

So far my express + graphql API is able to be bundled up into an EXE file. But how can I combine my Quasar app with this? I saw someone recommended I "create a parent application that spawns multiple child processes using the Cluster module of Node.js. Each child process can listen to a different port". Is this the best way? Surely other people must have used an API with Quasar, but im having problems finding any documentation on how this is deployable.

I have been reading about [Node 21 Single Executables](https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html) if you guys think that is a better starting point. I apologize for not having a whole lot of code, im very much at the initial planning stages, and want to make sure this is possible before I dump months into it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you had a look at Electron on the [Quasar Documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-electron-apps/introduction#introduction)?

You can run Node.js code within there, maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I ended up using the Node SAE route via ESBuild. I started with ESbuild, got that to crank thinngs down into one file, which I then bundled with Node. It workes amazing but getting ESbuild to work was really tricky.